# Spoofed DNS answers ignored by target machine applications

Tags: network, man-in-the-middle, dns, dns-spoofing

Attacker: Arch Linux

Target: Windows 10

**Scenario**
The attackers launches an ARP spoof attack to redirect all target traffic to the attacker. (This works)

The target sends DNS queries for domain name resolution to the attacker machine. (This works)

The attacker machine listens for this queries and if the query tries to resolve a specific domain (detectportal.firefox.com) sends an spoof DNS answer with the attacker's ip. For all the other domains the queries are not answered and not even forwarded.

Wireshark on both attacker and target machine confirms the reception of the spoofed dns answers although the applications that triggered the dns resolution seems to ignore this answers and just timeout.

**Example** on target machine:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
nslookup detectportal.firefox.com
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
Server: UnKnown
Address: 10.42.0.1  (my gateway ip and the ip being spoofed by the ARP attack)

DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.

DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.

DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.

DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
**** Request to UnKnown timed-out
```

Wireshark confirms the DNS spoof answers are correct and correlates them to the queries.

**Assumption:**

I do not compute the ip header checksum nor the udp checksum, just put some value (i.e. 0xdead, 0xbeef, 0xcafe). Could it be the target machine dropping these packets AFTER wireshark picks them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could it be the target machine dropping these packets AFTER wireshark picks them?

Wireshark gets the packets before they enter the IP stack, i.e. before any checksum gets checked and packets with bad checksum are discarded.

Comment: That was the problem. Computing the IP checksum fixed it. As a side note, there is no need to compute the UDP checksum, you can set it as 0x0. That means the checksum is disabled.